# Why website domain subpage auto redirect to localhost IP

Tags: wordpress, web, dns, localhost

I can access my company website's main page. But when i click on any subpages, it show 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. The domain auto change it to localhost.

When I clicked on the
Https://www.mycompany/contact link, it redirect to
Https://127.0.0.1/Contact.

This website has been deployed many years, but just happened this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the siteurl saved in your DB options table, change it to your live url and save the permalinks, it will work.